# Author affiliation in springer book svmono

Tags: titles, overleaf, author

I am writing a book using springer `svmono` class. However, I am not able to insert author's affiliation though class file has the following code for inserting `\institute` command. On using the `\institute` commamnd, nothing appears on the title page except author name, title of the book etc. I am using this template from overleaf [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-springer-monographs-slash-textbooks/jkmjvjrkqrpb). Any hint?

```
\newcounter{@inst}
\newcounter{@auth}
\newcounter{auco}
\newdimen\instindent
\newbox\authrun
\newtoks\authorrunning
\newtoks\tocauthor
\newbox\titrun
\newtoks\titlerunning
\newtoks\toctitle
\def\clearheadinfo{\gdef\@author{No Author Given}%
                   \gdef\@title{No Title Given}%
                   \gdef\@subtitle{}%
                   \gdef\@institute{}%
                   \gdef\@thanks{}%
                   \global\titlerunning={}\global\authorrunning={}%
                   \global\toctitle={}\global\tocauthor={}}
\def\institute#1{\gdef\@institute{#1}}
\def\guidetitle{\@ifstar\s@title\n@title}
\def\s@title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\ds@numart}
\def\n@title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\ds@book}
\def\institutename
 {\begingroup
 \if!\@institute!\else
 \def\thanks##1{\unskip{}}%
 \def\iand{\\[5pt]\let\and=\nand}%
 \def\nand{\ifhmode\unskip\nobreak\fi\ $\cdot$ }%
 \let\and=\nand
 \def\at{\\\let\and=\iand}%
 \footnotetext[0]{\kern-\bibindent
 \ignorespaces\@institute}\vspace{5dd}\fi
 \endgroup
 }%
```

Comment: The class file in the Overleaf template actually does not contain the code you've posted, so I'm not sure where you obtained that code. But the `svmono` class does not have this built-in. `svjour` does have a built-in `\institute` macro, but it doesn't match the definition you've given here. It may be best to contact Springer to see what they recommend here, `svmono` has a `\thanks` command which could be used, but the publisher may want something else done for this.

Comment: Did you actually click on open as a template? FYI, use this overleaf URL to open the template. https://www.overleaf.com/8166137568zxznpsgpttgm . Inside `svmono.cls`, seaarch for `\institute`.

Comment: yes, I did just that, and there is no `\institute` macro defined in the file. This is the case in both my own test project from the template which I created earlier, and your project you've shared here. Which line of `svmono.cls` are you looking at?

Comment: oops. Looks like I copy paste the above code from another .cls file which comes from another springer book template available [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/resources-guidelines/book-manuscript-guidelines/manuscript-preparation/5636). What I did was copy paste the above code in `svmono` and tried to see if it works which it did not.  I'm not able to fix it since I'm not latex pro. Hope it can help you fix it.

Comment: It's not normally good practice to directly edit distributed .cls files because it can make it tricky to debug problems if you have different contents in the class file than everyone else with the standard distributed version. Since Springer have provided an updated complete template that's newer than the version that was published on Overleaf, it's probably easiest to start from their template rather than Overleaf's version. You can do this by taking their `monographs.zip` and adding it in Overleaf by choosing New Project -> Upload Project from your Overleaf dashboard.

Comment: OK. I'll check it. Thanks.